# Running Ubuntu 14.04 and recently can't download from software center

Tags: authentication, error-handling

Download from software center not possible and got this message `" authentication error"`

I have tried all suggestions but still not fixed yet, I was wonder if anybody can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when you have PPAs installed. PPAs are technically not supported by Ubuntu so the best thing to do would be to remove the PPAs by using the Software & Updates app.

If you want to keep your PPAs, you can uncheck all the PPAs and then reenable them one by one (using the app I mentioned), using `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade` each time to find out which one is causing the issue. Then I would recommend using the Remove button to remove that PPA fully and then use `sudo add-apt-repository (the ppa)` to readd it. If the faulty PPA still isn't working then remove it and don't use it.

You should be able to just ignore the authentication issue entirely by using `sudo apt upgrade` and then `y` to carry on installing even though you don't have full authentication for the packages. This isn't particularly recommended(!) I would try the process above first.